# Apple Wallet pass balance update delay

Tags: apple-push-notifications, apns-php, javapns, apns-sharp

We have implemented an API service in .NET that sends background notifications to Apple Wallet to update its balance, which in turn calls below to APIs of our service:

1. `webServiceURL/version/devices/deviceLibraryIdentifier/registrations/passTypeIdentifier?passesUpdatedSince=tag`
2. `webServiceURLversion/passes/passTypeIdentifier/serialNumber`

Service sends a push notification to `api.push.apple.com:443` using HTTP/2 protocol and uses **Pass Type ID with NFC Certificate** for auth, with success every time and the wallet invokes the above two APIs hence balance gets updated.

However around 30% of the time, pass update happens with a delay; and the delay keeps on increasing like 1 min, 2 mins, 10 mins, 1 hour, and so on, and gets reset.

I tried to add a header `apns-expiration` with the value **UtcNow + 5 mins** in epoch format in the push notification request, but it did not work.